# Media por horas de un dato dependiendo del número de datos por hora SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

Necesito calcular la media de unos datos que dependiendo de que si el indicador que tengan (flag = 0 es valido), y supera los 45 registros a la hora que tienen el indicador flag= 0 me haga la media si no no haga la media. ¿Cómo lo podría hacer? Esto es lo que tengo, pero me hace la media de todos los datos que tengan flag = 0 , necesito hacerlo si solo hay mas de 45 por hora. ¿Es posible mediante el método count y un condicional o algo parecido? Esto es lo que tengo pero no funciona

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, Fecha) AS HORA, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE FLAG1 = 0)>45) THEN particulas else 
'DATOS NO VALIDOS' end ) AS PARTICULAS, 
   AVG(CASE WHEN FLAG2 = 0 THEN presion end) AS PRESION,
   AVG(CASE WHEN FLAG3 = 0 THEN presiondif end ) AS PRESDIF,
   AVG(CASE WHEN FLAG4 = 0 THEN temperaturasonda END) AS TEMPSONDA,
   AVG(CASE WHEN FLAG5 = 0 THEN temperatura  END) AS TEMPERATURA,
   AVG(CASE WHEN FLAG6 = 0 THEN caudal  END) AS CAUDAL
FROM filtro1
WHERE fecha >= '16-03-2020 16:11:00.370' and fecha <= '18-03-2020 19:20:00.370' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(Hour, Fecha);
```

La siguiente consulta si que me devuelve la media si tengo mas de 45 datos por hora con el flag = 0 pero no se como meterlo en la consulta de arriba en el case para que solo me haga esa media en caso de esta consulta. Gracias

```
select DATEPART(HOUR,Fecha) as HORA, avg(particulas) AS MEDIAPARTICULASVALIDA,
COUNT(flag1 ) AS DATOSVALIDOS from filtro1  where flag1 = 0
group by datepart(hour,fecha) having count(flag1)>45
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podes usar having para filtrar los resultados de un count de registros ;)

Comment: Me da error no es posible usar una funcion de agregado con una expresión que contiene un agregado o una subconsulta

Comment: Donde y como lo agregaste? Por favor edita tu pregunta y pone todo lo que probaste

Comment: actualizo la pregunta